# How to get data from inside (object-class) in a Drag-Drop operation ( DragEventArgs e )

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, attached-properties

im implementing a very common method for Drag-Drop operation using dependency properties, part of the code is shown below

the problem is, i need to get informations out from the draggedItem (defined as a object class), which is important for other calculations in the application

how can i get access to the data ? is it possible ? or should i define `draggedItem` as another type? thnx in advance!

```
private void DropTarget_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            object draggedItem = e.Data.GetData(this.format.Name);

            DecideDropTarget(e);
            if (draggedItem != null)
            {
                // Dragged Adorner is only updated here - it has already been created in DragEnter.
                ShowDraggedAdorner(e.GetPosition(this.topWindow));
                UpdateInsertionAdornerPosition();
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to know exactly what type that your `draggedObject` is before you can use any of its members. If you have created generic drag and drop functionality, then you need to add a property of type `Type` that will specify, maybe even validate what type of data is being dragged. If for instance, you knew that your `draggedObject` was of type `Address`, then you could simply cast it and then use the properties like this:

```
object draggedItem = e.Data.GetData(this.format.Name);
Address draggedAddress = (Address)draggedItem;
DoSomethingWith(draggedAddress.PostCode);
```